# mod_rewrite redirect host to another folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have some domains that all redirect to the same folder (my public_html). I'd like to write an .htaccess file that would send each domain to it's own folder (thus not displaying this on the navigation bar).
For example, navigating to http://example.com would load the folder `/public_html/example.com/` of my server.

In another context, I've used this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now I don't want to redirect to another domain; I just want to fetch the files from a different folder...

Is it achievable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace what you have with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]
```

---

For explicit host redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/$1  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} otherexample\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/otherexample.com/public_html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/otherexample.com/public_html/$1  [L]
```

Comment: But can I explicitly say that I want to redirect the "example.com"? Suppose that example.com would fetch the files from `/public_html/example.com/` but otherexample.com would lead to `/public_html/abc/otherexample.com/public_html`...

Comment: Yeah, you can make explicit host->directory mappings, see my edit

Comment: Behaves exactly how I was looking to. Thank you.